# Handling multiple properties file in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, properties-file

Our project used to have two kinds of properties in camel. One is for the default configuration and the other is a web service info. Once we package an entire project in a jar format. We placed the properties files in a separate folder (config). Which is present outside the jar file. Dynamically the web service properties are changed based on client requirements. It's better to keep it outside. So, to avoid every time building the jar file based on the web service property gets changed.

On reading the properties from the camel route, it was looking inside the jar directory of /config folder. We need to look outside of the /config folder.

[image]

The below code used to apply the properties

```
main.setPropertyPlaceholderLocations("file:config/scb-api-proxy.properties,config/scb-api-proxy-cred.properties,classpath:application.properties");
```

[image]

```
try {
            PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\config123\\";
            System.out.println("***** PATH" + path);
            pc.setLocation("file:" + path +"scb-api-proxy.properties," + path +"scb-api-proxy-cred.properties,classpath:application.properties");
            
 
            context.setPropertiesComponent(pc);
            
            LOG.info("Loading the properties file " +  context.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(
                    "{{smartcore.api.proxy.credential:false}}"
                    .toString()));
            
            }catch(Exception err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Where do you run the application from? You need to check the current working directory (`System.getProperties("user.dir")`.) If you are double-clicking, it might be you're running it from `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: @k314159,  The path where those files are kept in C:\Anto_Dev_Environment\proxy_wmi

Comment: Are you sure? How do you know it's that folder? If you double-click it, that folder is _not_ the current directory. Try putting `echo %CD% && pause` at the start of your `run_proxy.bat` and you'll see.

Comment: @k314159, I got the directory  'echo C:\Anto_Dev_Environment\proxy_wmi   && pause' I tried the above code..No luck.